# Unity3d Google Play Games InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm taking this error in Unity3d editor:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
LeaderboardFunctions.Show_COINS_Leaderboard () (at Assets/LeaderboardFunctions.cs:53)
```

But strange because i used same code other project but this project coming that.

```
((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(Leaderboard.leaderboard_highscores); PlayGamesPlatform giving error.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, we could only help if you provide more details about your problem. maybe you could show us the `LeaderboardFunction.cs` line 53. more details more easier to track the real issues

Comment: line 53 : ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(Leaderboard.leaderboard_highscores);